# Abrir un popup la primera vez que el usuario ingrese al sitioweb

Tags: javascript, popup

buenas necesito que me ayuden con esto, lo que sucede es lo siguiente estoy desarrolando una pagina web en la cual necesito que se muestre un popup solo la primera vez que el usuario ingrese a la web y que le vuelva a activar despues de una semana, he buscado y he encontrado un a solucion con utilizando cookies, pero tengo un problema que no me lo vuelve a mostar despues del tiempo que le asigno este es mi codigo en java sript que me hace la verificación de apertura:

```
var expDays = 1;
function GetCookie (name) {  
var arg = name + "="; 
  var alen = arg.length; 
  var clen = document.cookie.length; 
  var i = 0; 

  while (i < clen) { 
    var j = i + alen; 
   if (document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg) 
       return getCookieVal (j); 
      i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1; 
 if (i == 0) break; 
}
    return null;
}

function SetCookie (name, value) { 
  var argv = SetCookie.arguments; 
  var argc = SetCookie.arguments.length; 
  var expires = (argc > 2) ? argv[2] : null; 
  var path = (argc > 3) ? argv[3] : null; 
  var domain = (argc > 4) ? argv[4] : null; 
  var secure = (argc > 5) ? argv[5] : false; 
document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + 
((expires == null) ? "" : ("; expires=" + expires.toGMTString())) + 
((path == null) ? "" : ("; path=" + path)) + 
((domain == null) ? "" : ("; domain=" + domain)) + 
((secure == true) ? "; secure" : "");

}

function DeleteCookie (name) { 
  var exp = new Date(); 
  exp.setTime (exp.getTime() - 1); 
  var cval = GetCookie (name); 
  document.cookie = name + "=" + cval + "; expires=" + exp.toGMTString();

}

var exp = new Date(); 
exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + (expDays*24*60*60*1000));

function amt(){
  var count = GetCookie('count')

  if(count == null) {
    SetCookie('count','1')
    return 1
    } else {
       var newcount = parseInt(count) + 1;
       DeleteCookie('count')
       SetCookie('count',newcount,exp)
    return count

    }

}

function getCookieVal(offset) {
   var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf (";", offset);
   if (endstr == -1)
     endstr = document.cookie.length;
     return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
}



function checkCount() {
  var count = GetCookie('count');
  if (count == null) {
    count=1;
    SetCookie('count', count, exp);
    $(".popup-suscripcion").attr("style","display:block");
  } else {      
    $(".popup-suscripcion").attr("style","display:none");       
    count++;
    SetCookie('count', count, exp);
  }

}

window.onload=checkCount
```

Espero me puedan ayudar gracias

Comment: puedes usar localhost para guardar una variable con el dato fechaPantallaMostrada si al cargar la pagina no existe la variable muestras el popup y guardas la variable con la fechayhora y si existe la variable muetras el popup si la fecha actual menos fechaPantallaMostrada dia es mayor a 7.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código del `popup`? Quizá hay una forma más optima de mostrarlo.